# Return data when the OR operator conditions are true in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following query. Currently it checks on two conditions:

1. if one condition is true it will return the results for the first statement `(t1.ticket=t2.ticket and ( t1.type=t2.type)`
2. if this result is false then it will return results for the next condition `( t1.code=t2.code)`.

It does this is because sometimes this condition columns `(t1.ticket=t2.ticket and ( t1.type=t2.type))` are equal to null and some times this condition colums `( t1.code=t2.code)` are null thats why it switches between both.

But now what i noticed is that sometimes both the conditions return true and because of the `OR` statement its ignoring one of the conditions.
How do i return results for both of those conditions if they both there conditions are met? If its not met then they must return the one condition that matches.

```
    select t1.name 
           ,t1.ID
           ,t1.type
           ,t2.TicketID
           ,t2.Account
           ,t1.code
    from table 1 t1 
    inner join table 2 t2 
            on (t1.ticketID=t2.ticketID and t1.type=t2.type) 
            or ( t1.code=t2.code)
    left join table 3 t3 
            on t2.Res=t3.res
    left join table 4 t4 
            on t3.IdDetail=t4.idDetail
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: this is the result that i get now from the above query,it ignores the other 2 records even though its there]

Comment: Show sample data and expected result

Comment: Unclear what you are asking.  Please include sample data for your question.  Also, the query you did include would not even run on SQL Server.

Comment: I read the question several times but it's still not clear what you're actually asking. Could you please provide sample data and desired output to clearify?

Comment: Btw, it's best to add the simplified sample data & expected result as text. Makes it easier for the one who wants to spend their free time on it. (typing the mock data yourself takes more effort)

Comment: @Jens i have added some sample data

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen  sample data has been added

Comment: @RobertKock sample data has been added

Comment: Can you indicate what the coloured bars mean in your sample? and what is the _current_ result?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i was just trying to show which columns they are joined on

Comment: You've posted the expected result but what is the _current_ result?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i just updated it

Comment: I see no reason that account 4575 wouldn't come through. Firstly, make sure you don't have a `WHERE` that is excluding outer joined records from t3 and t4 (in fact remove them altogether to simplify the code). Secondly wrap the whole `ON` in brackets like this:  `on ( (t1.ticketID=t2.ticketID and t1.type=t2.type) or ( t1.code=t2.code) )` just in case

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid what about the 3rd result

Comment: Once we understand the second result, the third result will probably fix itself for the same reason. If it doesn't we address it. If you're not going to action my comment I'm not going to do a full analysis of the issue.

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using left join

```
    select t1.name 
               ,t1.ID
               ,COALESCE(t2.Ticket,t22.Ticket) as Ticket
               ,COALESCE(t2.Account,t22.Account) as Account
               ,COALESCE(t2.code,t22.code) as code
               ,t22.type
               ,t3.res
        ,t1.type
        from table1 t1 left join table2 t2 on (t1.ticket=t2.ticket and t1.code=t2.code) 
    left join t22 on ( t1.type=t22.type)
    left join table3 t3 on t2.Res=t3.res
left join table4 t4 on t3.IdDetail=t4.idDetail
```

If you want both result of table2 then no need use `COALESCE` function

Comment: i updated the question with the expected results,the above query doesn't help me in achieving the required request.its just going to switch between to options and not give me the result when both matches

Comment: @john here your answer is alredy in this query just select type in selection

Comment: i tried the exact same query and its only returning result for one condition,it completely ignores the left join t22 condition

Comment: @john could you please https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c80a2b7563ffcc196d939f5512d3aca5 create here your table with data insert so i can test

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to add a calculated column as hash of ticket, on both table1 and table2 code and type on all the tables, then using it as a new 'surrogate' key, a trigger to generate it each time a row is  updated.

```
ALTER TABLE T1 ADD 
NEW_KEY AS (hashbytes('SHA1',CONCAT(TICKET,CODE,TYPE)))


ALTER TABLE T2 ADD 
NEW_KEY AS (hashbytes('SHA1',CONCAT(TICKET,CODE,TYPE)))

UPDATE TABLE T2 SET NEW_KEY = hashbytes('SHA1',CONCAT(TICKET,CODE,TYPE)) WHERE NEW_KEY IS NULL

UPDATE TABLE T1 SET NEW_KEY = hashbytes('SHA1',CONCAT(TICKET,CODE,TYPE)) WHERE NEW_KEY IS NULL
```